# Is it possible to share media files between multiple WordPress sites?

Tags: attachments, media-library

We've got around ten or so WP sites on different instances of WP (each with it's own database), most of them are on the same server but not all of them. We would like to achieve a situation where an editor can upload an image on one site and it will automatically show up in the media library on all the other sites.

I guess we need two things:

- Some sort of CDN or shared file storage
- A plugin that (automatically) adds media files from the file storage into the WordPress database

Shouldn't be that hard to accomplish, right? :)

1. Does anyone know of an off-the-shelf solution to this?
2. If we were to build this ourselves, what do you think will be the main challenges for us to overcome?